# .Net Framework error in c#

Tags: c#, dll, .net-framework-version

I have an A.dll file. I am using this in in project B.

1. Using .Net Framework 4.5 A.dll and B working fine
2. Using .Net Framework 4.0 A.dll and B working fine

But when-

3. Using .Net Framework 3.5 A.dll is building successfully. But Project B getting following Error/Warning when using A.dll

   **Warning** 1   The primary reference "A, Version=1.0.5914.2979, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

   **Error**   The type or namespace name 'A' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How I can solve this? Need it to build for lower version of .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/158761

Comment: The compiler says exactly how to resolve this. Dont compile A under .NET 3.5, or, alternatively remove all the .NET 4.0 dependencies from it.

Comment: Why would you compile it under 3.5 when it works fine under 4.0 & 4.5?

Comment: In Win7 If I install it then it prompts to install .Net Framework upper version 4/4.5 but I don't want to install .Net Framework. Win7 has default 3.5

Comment: Version=1.0.5914.2979 says that A was built 2 days ago, March 11th at 1:39 AM in the morning.  Not sure what kind of working hours y'all keep but in all likelihood you are using an old build of A, one that was built for 4.0 by a build server.  Just like the error message says.  Update the reference.